# TSX to JSX transformation doesn't match closing tag correctly

Tags: typescript, tsx

With following TSX code :

```
Import {Provider} from "react-redux"

ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider>
          <App />
        </Provider> , document.getElementById('app')
      );
```

I get following JSX code when using 'preserve' option:

```
ReactDOM.render(<react_redux_1.Provider>
      <App_1.default />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

"/Provider" closing tag doesn't match "react_redux_1.Provider" opening tag

What am i doing wrong ?

typescript 1.8.0-dev.20151204
Target es5
Modules commonjs
jsx preserve

Answer (score 1):

> What am i doing wrong ?

Nothing. Bug in the compiler. Reported : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5962

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed in Master
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5974
Thanks.